# What is the cause of error on React Navigation, 'this.props.navigation' being undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting and error when implementing basic React Navigation. This error appears when launching the app, When i comment out line 'const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;' there is no error.

**App.js** code

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, 
Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator,} from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './myviews/Home';

export default class Myapp extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
 title: 'Welcome',
};
constructor (props)
{
super(props);
this.state = {
 text : 'Hi there...'
 ,username : ''
 ,password : ''}
 }
login = () => {

}
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
let text = this.state.text;
return (
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style = {styles.container}>
      <View style = {styles.child1}>

      </View>
      <View style = {styles.child2}>
            <Text>{text} </Text>
            <TextInput onChangeText = {(value)=>this.setState({username:value})} style = {styles.txtBig} placeholder = "username or email"></TextInput>
            <TextInput onChangeText = {(value)=>this.setState({password:value})} style = {styles.txtBig} placeholder = "password" ></TextInput>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={()=>{ this.login() }}>
               <Text style={styles.txt}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
              title="Go home"
            />
      </View>
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
 }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
Myapp: { screen: Myapp },
Home: { screen: Home },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#7fffd4',
  },
 child1 : {
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 justifyContent : 'space-around',
 alignItems : 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#00ffff',
 },
 child2 : {
 flex: 1,
 alignItems : 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#ff8c00',
},
grandchild1 : {
 width:150,
  height:50,
  backgroundColor : '#ff8c00',

 },
 grandchild2 : {
  width:150,
  height:50,
  backgroundColor : '#8fbc8f'
 },
txtBig : {
width : 300,
marginTop : 10,
backgroundColor : 'white',
borderWidth: 3,
borderColor : 'white',
paddingHorizontal : 10,
fontSize : 20,
color : '#ff8c00',
height : 50,
},
txt : {
textAlign : 'center',
fontSize : 20,
color : '#ff8c00',
fontWeight : '700'
},
button : {
   backgroundColor : '#ffd700',
  width : 300,
  height : 50,
  paddingHorizontal : 10,
  paddingVertical : 10,
  marginTop : 10,
}
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Myapp', () => App);
```

In my **render()** If comment out 'this.props.navigation' there is no error
And i am not seeing the 'Welcome' title on myApp screen either

**Home.js** code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, 
    KeyboardAvoidingView, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

  export default class Home extends React.Component {
 constructor (props)
  {
   super(props);
  }

  render() {

  return (
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style = {styles.container}>
      <View style = {styles.child1}>
          <Text>Welcome Home</Text>
      </View>
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );

  }

 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
   backgroundColor: '#7fffd4',
 },
child1 : {
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 justifyContent : 'space-around',
 alignItems : 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#00ffff',
  },
  });
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => Home);
```

Comment: Show valid code then we can help. Your code for `App.js` is not valid JavaScript at all.

Comment: You have syntax error in App.js

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I have included entire code fro App.js and Home.js

Comment: i think your code so confused... please can you show valid code ?

Comment: @muhammadaa - whats invalid about this code, there is no syntax errors i copied this from straight from IDE

Answer (score 0):

just change in component `render()` **App.js** on line :

`const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

to

`const navigate = this.props.navigation;`

on my emulator, your code show like :

[image]

*Edit*#1: this is update answer.

I follow the official website for `react-navigation`, your code above is absolutely nothing wrong. However, you missed something wrong probably in the file `index.android.js` when you import file **App.js**. Maybe you can just write in file `index.android.js` like :

`import './App';`

And you can try run again your app.

in my emulator, your code showing like :
**App.js**

[image: App.js]

when i klik button, then show :

**Home.js**

[image: Home.js]

i hope my answer can help you.. thank you.

Comment: The error is gone on launch, but 
    `onPress={() => navigate('Home')}` has an error now, 
**'Undefined is not a function evaluating navigate('Home')'**

Comment: if you are using 

const navigate = this.props.navigation;

your button press should look like this

onPress={() => navigate.navigate('Home')}

Comment: @AfricaMatjie i think the problem in `StackNavigator()`, because when i `console.log` the `this.props.navigation`. the result is `undefined`. maybe first you can try tutorial in [official web](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) to use this library.

Comment: @AfricaMatjie can you show code in `index.android.js` ? after i follow tutorial in official web, I get some steps you might miss.
I make a change, I show in the answer above.. maybe can help you.

Comment: i finally figured it out myself. thanks for ur effort.

Comment: i glad to help you bro @AfricaMatjie.. thumbs up!!

Comment: @muhammadaa - like i said, i figured it out myself. all u guys did was roast me, which is expected from SO comments anyway..things like 'ur code is confused/invalid', Whatsup with that

Comment: oh oke bro @AfricaMatjie, sorry for that... I really appreciate for your hard work. I just want to both learn from your problem.